# Default controller not work with my fxml

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have no clue why this code does not work. I have created an fxml document using Scene Builder and all it does is add a borderpane. So far I only get errors when trying  to call my fxml. I think it might be because the program dose not think I initialized some of my variables, but I don;t know why.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class SampleController {
    @FXML
    Pane mainPane;
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        System.out.println(mainPane.getHeight());
    }
}
```

hears the fxml file created.

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.SampleController">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <center>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <center>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="273.0" prefWidth="1104.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Pane fx:id="taskPane" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="4.0" minHeight="259.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <children>
                        <ScrollPane layoutX="19.0" layoutY="54.0" prefHeight="205.0" prefWidth="337.0">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="235.0" prefWidth="290.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <VBox layoutX="1.0" prefHeight="238.0" prefWidth="297.0" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                        <Button layoutX="39.0" layoutY="16.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New Habit" />
                        <Label layoutX="152.0" layoutY="21.0" text="Habits">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="22.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
                  <Pane layoutX="376.0" layoutY="7.0" minHeight="259.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <children>
                        <ScrollPane layoutX="19.0" layoutY="54.0" prefHeight="205.0" prefWidth="337.0">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="235.0" prefWidth="290.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <VBox layoutX="1.0" prefHeight="238.0" prefWidth="297.0" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                        <Button layoutX="39.0" layoutY="16.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New Task" />
                        <Label layoutX="152.0" layoutY="21.0" text="Dayley Tasks">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="22.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
                  <Pane layoutX="748.0" layoutY="15.0" minHeight="259.0" prefHeight="259.0" prefWidth="356.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <children>
                        <ScrollPane layoutX="19.0" layoutY="54.0" prefHeight="205.0" prefWidth="337.0">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="235.0" prefWidth="290.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <VBox layoutX="1.0" prefHeight="238.0" prefWidth="297.0" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                        <Button layoutX="39.0" layoutY="16.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New ToDo" />
                        <Label layoutX="152.0" layoutY="21.0" text="To Do List">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="22.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </AnchorPane>
         </center>
         <top>
            <Pane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="400.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </top>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </BorderPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

this is what my project looks like.
[enter image description here][1]

```
[Main (3) [Java Application]    
    application.Main at localhost:34867 
        Thread [main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
            SystemProperties.setVersions() line: 81 
            SystemProperties.lambda$static$55() line: 67    
            1917513796.run() line: not available    
            AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>) line: not available [native method]  
            SystemProperties.<clinit>() line: 64    
            LauncherImpl.startToolkit() line: 668   
            LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(String, String, String[]) line: 337  
            LauncherImpl.launchApplication(String, String, String[]) line: 328  
            NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
            NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 62  
            DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
            Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 498  
            LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(String...) line: 767   
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (Mar 24, 2018, 5:19:54 PM)   
][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThjM6.png
  [2]: http://eror.com
```

Comment: Can you include your project file tree and is your fxml file in the project

Comment: dose that image help

Comment: Before we go further can you try going into your fxml and where is says fx:controller="application.SampleController" changing it to fx:controller="SampleController" and tell me if that fixes it

Comment: Actually I found your problem you never assigned a pane fx:id="mainPane"

Comment: same errors  as last time when i started pro.

Comment: also could you include the full error text

Comment: this should hafe added the text id <Pane fx:id="mainPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />

Comment: that is a lot of text is there a way to link a text file hear.

Comment: yes just add a paste bin link. Also did you just add that pane because I can't find it in your fxml.

Comment: cant find the past bin link

Comment: after you create the paste copy the url and add it to your post

Comment: just added the error list

Comment: Just one more thing can you include your css I don't think its the problem but it might be

Comment: i think i might have figured it out my debugger is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have fixed it try replacing your fxml with this

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.SampleController">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <center>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <center>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="273.0" prefWidth="1104.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Pane fx:id="taskPane" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="4.0" minHeight="259.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <children>
                        <ScrollPane layoutX="19.0" layoutY="54.0" prefHeight="205.0" prefWidth="337.0">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="235.0" prefWidth="290.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <VBox layoutX="1.0" prefHeight="238.0" prefWidth="297.0" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                        <Button layoutX="39.0" layoutY="16.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New Habit" />
                        <Label layoutX="152.0" layoutY="21.0" text="Habits">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="22.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
                  <Pane layoutX="376.0" layoutY="7.0" minHeight="259.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <children>
                        <ScrollPane layoutX="19.0" layoutY="54.0" prefHeight="205.0" prefWidth="337.0">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="235.0" prefWidth="290.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <VBox layoutX="1.0" prefHeight="238.0" prefWidth="297.0" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                        <Button layoutX="39.0" layoutY="16.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New Task" />
                        <Label layoutX="152.0" layoutY="21.0" text="Dayley Tasks">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="22.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
                  <Pane layoutX="748.0" layoutY="15.0" minHeight="259.0" prefHeight="259.0" prefWidth="356.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <children>
                        <ScrollPane layoutX="19.0" layoutY="54.0" prefHeight="205.0" prefWidth="337.0">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="235.0" prefWidth="290.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <VBox layoutX="1.0" prefHeight="238.0" prefWidth="297.0" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                        <Button layoutX="39.0" layoutY="16.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New ToDo" />
                        <Label layoutX="152.0" layoutY="21.0" text="To Do List">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="22.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </AnchorPane>
         </center>
         <top>
            <Pane fx:id="mainPane" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="400.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </top>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </BorderPane>
   </center>
```